# what is an application for the return directive in PHP, outside of a function

Tags: php

I just encountered the use of `return` in a PHP framework (Laravel 4) which I am new to.

I understand what it does, as follows:

```
# contents of file A
<?php
//this is fileA.php
echo '<pre>';
echo "here is from file A\n";
$output = require('fileB.php');
echo $output;  // "Hi, I am the return value from file B"
?>

# contents of file B
<?php 
echo "Hi, I am content inside file B\n";
$return = "Hi, I am the return value from file B";
return $return;  //terminate page processing..
//should not show
echo "I bet you don't see me\n";
<?php
```

the above outputs:

```
Here is from file A
Hi, I am content inside file B
Hi, I am return value from file B
```

My question is, when is it advisable (or even on God's green earth thinkable!) to use something like this?

This seems analogous to `return` in a function but essentially makes an included file a "quasi-function" and blurs the lines between object oriented (or even procedural) coding and essentially elevates a file to the level of a method or a class.

Again, I'm wondering when such a thing would be advisable *OVER* an OOP application.

Oh, and did Laravel have any particular idea in mind in implementing this so often...

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel?

Comment: TAYQ, the fact that it is used quite a bit with Laravel 4 only.  Maybe, just perhaps, someone might have some helpful design comments on why Laravel developers used this.  I know I haven't come across anything like this yet.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly what you see there, and it is not Laravel related, but strictly PHP related (and not OOP related at all, this has nothing to do with that and it is not an *alternative* or anything of the like).

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. **If the current script file was included or required**, then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, **if the current script file was included, then the value given to return will be returned as the value of the include call.**

It's typically used for configuration files: you define a configuration, and return it; so the consumer for the config can just include the file and use the returned value without having to access or know about the details from the included/required file.

E.g., a pattern you'll encounter will be something along the lines of:

```
// config.php
return [
   'config_key' => 'config_value'
];

// config.consummer.php
$config = include "config.php";
```

Now you have the resulting array in `$config`, and you can include bits of logic in your configuration file if required, and your application needs not to know anything about your config file but that it "returns an array".

**Addressing a few comments**

There are a couple of advantages of processing config files directly in PHP: you can embed some moderate amount of logic (think`realpath`, some basic arithmetic), IDE support, no need to learn a new language/markup, and most importantly, **opcaching**.

Some frameworks deal with this by allowing you to use a simpler, more limited language (yaml, xml, etc) and precompiling/caching this configuration to PHP on first execution, to gain the ease of use of a simpler markup and the performance benefits of using PHP files.

But somewhere, no matter what you do, and include/require is taking place if your configuration comes from PHP files. Nobody is saying you should include this files willy-nilly, I was just explaining why this kind of thing the OP found was being done.

And again: **this has nothing to to vs oo or procedural programming**. This is just and idiomatic facility provided by PHP, which can be used whenever is reasonable and convenient.

Comment: Personally I would cry bitter tears of sadness if I'd come across this. I see no use of this 'pattern' at all, and while this is a very good answer for the question (so no downvote) I would strongly suggest NOT using this :)

Comment: It's a very common pattern in, for example, ZF2 configuration files (among other places, so not rare at all). It has a very valid use, IMO.

Comment: It might be a matter of taste, but having a seemingly 'random' include hidden like that really gives me the creeps. But as there are better configuration options that do not require this functionality I would still argue against using this. But again, it is a personal thing or maybe a "cultural" (as in what you are used to from your peers in programming) thing. But again, nothing wrong with this answer, I just wanted to mention my feelings. Here, have an upvote to compensate for my rant :)

Comment: When you see it in use (and its unusual if you haven't encountered it yet), it's never "hidden" or "random". The example provided by the OP would (should) never exist in production code. When you see it in configuration files, it makes sense: files with almost NO logic, almost entirely declarative, and ending on a return. More often than not, they just declare and return an array and that's it.

Comment: it's not the return I find random, it's the `include` :)

Comment: Check this [implementation](https://dasprids.de/blog/2009/05/08/writing-powerful-and-easy-config-files-with-php-arrays/). This is old, but you'll get the idea. Still, you are free to dislike it. :)

Comment: I agree that I _DONT_ like this; that said, the implementation link by @yivi is cool - I just wouldn't do it via an include - there should be a more abstracted way than an include file and often, config information should be parseable by more than just PHP.  Just my opinions on this.  `include()` should be abstracted to an OOP method of getting the data.

Comment: The other point is, your array works for THAT FUNCTION.  What's the point?  Shouldn't your config information be general in nature, with a function or method pulling what it needs.

Comment: @OliverWilliams , many of these things are a matter of opinion, and some or them simply knowing more about the language and these patterns. I was mostly trying to explain it to you. The other discussion is beyond the scope of SO. Please remember to accept/up vote if you find the answer useful. :)